# RaisePropertyChange WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

why RaisePropertyChange is not working inside

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        private string _searchString;
        public string SearchString
        {
            get { return _searchString; }
            set
            {
                _searchString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchPersonEHistroy);
            }
        }
}
```

It gives error **"RaisePropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context"**

but when i tried to use like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }

        public class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
        {
            private string _searchString;
            public string SearchString
            {
                get { return _searchString; }
                set
                {
                    _searchString = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchPersonEHistroy);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

what's the difference between them? or do we have any convertion for RaisePropertyChange inside **public partial class MainWindow : Window**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RaisePropertyChanged()` is defined by the `NotificationObject` class, not `Window`.

Since `Window` is already a `DependencyObject` you should make its `SearchString` property a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) which will allow you to bind it with the `SearchString` property of the View Model.

Comment: is there anyway i can use same raisepropertychange in window class?

Comment: You should use dependency properties.